# mysql search does not return value

Tags: php, mysql

I have an query like this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status="active" AND product_name LIKE "%sony\'s%"
```

but it does not return result while in products table I have a product named "Sony\'s"

Please give me solutio if anybody have.

Thanks

Comment: Is the value in the database literally `Sony\'s`? If so you've mangled your data by double escaping it during an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php


    $name = "active";
    $value = "%" + $product_name + "%";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
                           FROM  products
                           WHERE status = ? AND 
                                 product_name LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to use records with single quotes.

Comment: It's odd you're declaring your bindings before the values. This does work, though, right?

Comment: @tadman as far as the manual says, i "think" yes. [*Prepared statements and stored procedures*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) hehe

Answer (score 1):

Replace "%sony\'s%" with `'%sony''s%'`

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status="active" AND product_name LIKE '%sony''s%'
```